# Foreach in middle of return statement

Tags: php

I'm working on a tagging system for an image site, and I have:

```
function formatImage($url, $description, $tags){

if(empty($description)){

    $description = "<i>No description avaliable.</i>";

}

$tags = array("One", "Two");
$added = "May 23, 2011";

return '
    <div id="single" class="image">
        <div id="image">
            <img src="'.$url.'" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="meta">

        <dl>
            <dt>Description</dt>

            <dd>'.$description.'</dd>
            <dt>Added on</dt>
            <dd>'.$added.'</dd>
            <dt>Tagged</dt>
            <dd id="tags">'.
                foreach($tags as $tag){
                    return '<a href="/tagged/'.$tag.'">'.$tag.'</a>;
                }
                .'
            </dd>
        </dl>

    </div>';
```

And then farther down in functions.php:

```
function pullImage($id){

    dbCon();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $url = $row['url'];
    $description = $row['description'];

    //Tags
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tags WHERE itemid='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $tags = array();        

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        array_push($tags, $row['tag']);

    }

    //$tags = $tags;

    $image = formatImage($url, $description, $tags);

    echo $image;

}
```

And the problem I have is the `foreach` inside the `return` statement of the format function. I'm really confused as to how to make this work. How does one go about a function inside a return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the foreach earlier in your code:

```
$tagList = array();
foreach($tags as $tag){
    $tagList[] = '<a href="/tagged/'.$tag.'">'.$tag.'</a>';
}
return '
    <div id="single" class="image">
        <div id="image">
            <img src="'.$url.'" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="meta">
        <dl>
            <dt>Description</dt>

            <dd>'.$description.'</dd>
            <dt>Added on</dt>
            <dd>'.$added.'</dd>
            <dt>Tagged</dt>
            <dd id="tags">'.implode(', ', $tagList).'</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use output buffering in your function like this:

```
function formatImage($url, $description, $tags){
    //...
    ob_start();
    ?><div etc...
    ...
    <?php
    foreach (...) {
        ?><a href="...">...<?php
    }
    $output .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $output;
}
```

This could affect any existing output (depending on your application is set up) so you would want to call `formatImage()` before anything is output, possibly by wrapping the page in some kind of View container (like how an MVC framework like CakePHP or CodeIgniter works).